# Using DISTINCT to filter duplicates?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have the following query, and would like to list only the first match.

```
$first = $_GET['category'];
$first = $first[0] . "%";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE authorclean LIKE '".$first."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

(?category=b)

So DISTINCT could do this right? This is what I tried, but did not work:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT authorclean FROM lyrics WHERE authorclean LIKE '".$first."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT: Here is the full code:**

```
function getCategory() {
$first = $_GET['category'];
$first = $first[0] . "%";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT authorclean FROM lyrics WHERE authorclean LIKE 'B%'") or die(mysql_error());
//$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE authorclean LIKE '".$first."'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    echo "Geen resultaten gevonden.";
} else { 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
    <p><a href="/<?= $_GET['category']; ?>/<?= strtolower($row['authorclean']); ?>/"><?= $row['author']; ?></a></p>
    <?php }
    }
}
```

(B% is just for testing)

If I run this following query in the database directly I get two results. If I run with the code above I just get an empty page (except for the html thats already there).

```
SELECT DISTINCT authorclean FROM lyrics WHERE authorclean LIKE 'B%'
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Did you get an error? Did you get the wrong results? Also please read up on SQL injection. Don't use any external inputs directly in an SQL query without escaping them.

Comment: It doesn't return any results, just an empty page.No error messages.

Comment: Have you dumped the actual query and run that directly against the db to see if it is returning any results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a a table "tbl_lyrics" with fields: author lyrics year and is filled for example as follows:

```
author_A       lyrics_A        year_A
author_A       lyrics_A1       year_A1
author_A1       lyrics_A2       year_A
author_B        lyrics_B1       year_B1
```

if you do

```
select distinct(author) from tbl_lyrics where author like '%author_A%'
```

you are going to get: author_A and author_A1.  NOT the first one that matches.

If you want the first one that matches you can do:

```
select author from (select distinct(author) as author from tbl_lyrics where author like '%author_A%') where rownum <2;
```

this will return author_A only.

Limit is used with MySql but would not work with oracle databases

Answer (score 2):

You should use `LIMIT 1` to list only the first match.

Comment: When using limit in this way you should also have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @nnichols This depends on which order the op wants.

Comment: agreed. Just wanted OP  to be aware that there should be an ORDER BY clause, otherwise the query is non-deterministic.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt make myself really clear. I want to list every artist that starts with the letter B. So Beatles, Blink 182, Breaking Benjamin etc. Currently I output Beatles 4 times, since I have four matches in my DB. I only want it to display once.

Comment: As asked by liquorvicar, what do you mean by "did not work"? Your DISTINCT query looks fine to me although there is no need to jump in and out of the double quotes. Just do - `WHERE authorclean LIKE '$first'"`